# Concept similar to extended real line in higher dimensions?

Tags: real-numbers, infinity

I have a question related to the notion of extended real line. I am a very beginner of this topic and in what follows I might say things that look no-sense for an expert in the field.

The extended real line is the real line $\mathbb{R}$ plus $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. Is there a similar notion for an Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^k$ with $k>1$?

Comment: There are two "natural" infinities in the real line, due to it being totally ordered. In higher dimensions, we usually add one point at infinity, in a process that can be applied to any space (it is called the one-point compactification.)

Comment: I'm asking this because I'm confused by the way in which the expectation of a random vector $X:\Omega \rightarrow\mathbb{R}^k$ on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ is defined. Let $P$ be the probability distribution of $X$. When $k=1$ $E(X):=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} t dP$ which means integrating over the extended real line. What if $k>1$?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ is not "integrating over the extended real line," It is just integrating over the real line. It is just notation - you can write it as: $\int_{\mathbb R}$ rather and mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two "natural" infinities in the real line, due to it being totally ordered. In higher dimensions, we usually add one point at infinity, in a process that can be applied to any space (it is called the one-point compactification.)

Topologically, the one-point compactification of $\mathbb R^n$ can be see as an $n$-sphere.

For example, the one-point compactification of the real line is a circle (because we've essentially joined $-\infty$ and $+\infty$ into one point.)

There is another way to add infinities to $\mathbb R^n$: $\mathbb RP^n$ is the $n$-dimensional projective space, and it has a point at infinity for every class of parallel lines in $\mathbb R^n$.

As a topological space, $\mathbb RP^n$ is a bit odder, but it can be seen as an $n$-sphere with anti-podal points identified. When $n=1$, this is still just a circle, but when $n>1$, you get a space that is not "orientable," much like the Möbius strip.

Comment: There's also the [Stone-Cech compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93%C4%8Cech_compactification), but I have no earthly idea what that looks like

Comment: How about adding two points at infinity for each class of parallel lines in $\mathbb R^n $? Does anyone ever do that?

Comment: It's certainly do-able - then you get a topological disk. Nobody does this, that I know. The problem is there is no "continuous" way to pick which of those two infinities is plus and which is minus.